# VBA added values from a range gives wrong result?

Tags: excel, vba

i have a small dataset which is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3dPe.png)

i wrote a for loop that iterates through the values and add them one after another, however it treated the negative values as positive. the final result as you can see is just addition without subtracting the negative. have i done something wrong?

```
 for i = 1 to 28
         sum = sum + ws.range("B" & i).value
    next i
```

All suggestion and help are highly appreciated?

Comment: How sum is declared?

Comment: dim Sum as long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Sum(Ws.Range("B1:B28"))` will give the correct result. Whether or not you can assign it to a variable by the name of `Sum` depends upon the capability of that variable to hold the kind of value that results.

Observe that your function starts its loop from B0 which doesn't exist and, therefore, should cause an error if not a crash.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems to work better. However it returns the 4 instead of 0.